# Bubbling mouse event to parent canvas that is of chart.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, chart.js

I implemented custom tooltip over chart.js chart by using div that is moving above chart. My tooltip is somehow catching mouse events what is probably expected but I want to propagate it to parent element chart so data points are updated correctly and tooltip get repositioned. I didn't get how to do it as mostly people are trying to do opposite. As you see I tried some bubbling by calling emit directly on chart or as is seen in code by just simply calling emit.

Tooltip template looks like this:

```
<template>
<div :style="computedStyle" class="tooltip" @mouseover="$emit('mouseover')" @mousemove="$emit('mousemove')">
    <div ref="tooltip-background" v-html="svg" class="tooltip-background"/>
    <div class="tooltip-content">
        <div v-for="item of this.items">
            <div class="tooltip-content-values">
                <span class="">User activity: </span>
                <span class="tooltip-content-values-value">{{item.value}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tooltip-content-date">{{date}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
}

.tooltip-background {
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1
}

.tooltip-content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 15px;
}

.tooltip-content-values {
    font-family: Work Sans, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #666666;
}

.tooltip-content-values-value {
    font-family: Work Sans, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #111111;
}

.tooltip-content-date {
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: Work Sans, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #666666;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>
```

Comment: can you share a codesandbox or a blitz to check the scenario ?

Comment: Would the CSS property `pointer-events: none` work for you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: @EduardoPáezRubio thank you my friend, it works exactly as I needed, if you write answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to prevent mouse events on your elements and, as a result, getting them in the element behind is using the CSS property [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

For your case, simply set the property with the value none in your tooltip class:

```
.tooltip {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
}
```